# what is the best way to handle entity initial value in flutter

Tags: flutter

When I define a object in flutter(2.0.1) like this:

```
Item article = Item();
```

it tell me that I should give default parameter like this:

```
  Item article = Item(pubTime: null, id: '', dead: null);
```

but the Item have so many field, so the code will be very long and look ugly. This is the Item defined:

```
class Item {
  Item({
    this.depth = 0,
    required this.author,
    required this.deleted,
    required this.content,
    required this.dead,
    required this.poll,
    required this.parent,
    required this.parts,
    required this.descendants,
    required this.id,
    required this.kids,
    required this.score,
    required this.pubTime,
    required this.title,
    required this.type,
    required this.link,
    required this.isFav,
    required this.favCount,
    required this.subSourceId,
    required this.isUpvote,
    required this.upvoteCount
  });

  int depth;
  String author;
  bool deleted;
  String content;
  bool dead;
  int poll;
  int parent;
  List<int> parts;
  int descendants;
  String id;
  List<int> kids;
  int score;
  int pubTime;
  String title;
  StoryType type;
  String link;
  int isFav;
  int favCount;
  int isUpvote;
  int upvoteCount;
  String subSourceId;

  factory Item.fromJson(String str) => Item.fromMap(json.decode(str));

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  bool isVoted() => HistoryManager.isVoted(id);

  String get domain => Uri.parse(link).host;
  String get ago =>
      timeago.format(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(pubTime));

  factory Item.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Item(
    id: json["id"],
    author: json["author"] == null ? "" : json["author"],
    deleted: json["deleted"] == null ? false : json["deleted"],
    content: json["content"] == null ? "" : json["content"],
    dead: json["dead"] == null ? false : json["dead"],
    poll: json["poll"] == null ? null : json["poll"],
    parent: json["parent"] == null ? null : json["parent"],
    parts: json["parts"] == null
        ? []
        : List<int>.from(json["parts"].map((x) => x)),
    descendants: json["descendants"] == null ? 0 : json["descendants"],
    kids: json["kids"] == null
        ? []
        : List<int>.from(json["kids"].map((x) => x)),
    score: json["score"] == null ? 0 : json["score"],
    pubTime: json["pubTime"] == null ? 0 : json["pubTime"],
    title: json["title"] == null ? "" : json["title"],
    type: json["type"] == null ? StoryType.job : castType(json["type"]),
    link: json["link"] == null ? "" : json["link"],
    isFav: json["isFav"] == null ? "" : json["isFav"],
    favCount: json["favCount"] == null ? "" : json["favCount"],
    isUpvote: json["isUpvote"] == null ? "" : json["isUpvote"],
    upvoteCount: json["upvoteCount"] == null ? "" : json["upvoteCount"],
    subSourceId: json["subSourceId"] == null ? "" : json["subSourceId"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "id": id,
    "author": author == null ? null : author,
    "deleted": deleted == null ? null : deleted,
    "content": content == null ? null : content,
    "dead": dead == null ? null : dead,
    "poll": poll == null ? null : poll,
    "parent": parent == null ? null : parent,
    "parts": parts == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(parts.map((x) => x)),
    "descendants": descendants == null ? null : descendants,
    "kids": kids == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(kids.map((x) => x)),
    "score": score == null ? null : score,
    "pubTime": pubTime == null ? null : pubTime,
    "title": title == null ? null : title,
    "type": type == null ? null : type,
    "link": link == null ? null : link,
    "isFav": isFav == null ? null : isFav,
    "favCount": favCount == null ? null : favCount,
    "isUpvote": isUpvote == null ? null : isUpvote,
    "upvoteCount": upvoteCount == null ? null : upvoteCount,
    "subSourceId": subSourceId == null ? null : subSourceId,
  };

  static StoryType castType(String type) {
    switch (type) {
      case "job":
        return StoryType.job;
        break;
      case "story":
        return StoryType.story;
        break;
      case "comment":
        return StoryType.comment;
        break;
      case "poll":
        return StoryType.poll;
        break;
      case "pollopt":
        return StoryType.pollopt;
        break;
      default:
        return StoryType.job;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

what should I do to give a default value for the Item a better way? I do not want to define like this:

```
Item? article;
```

because I do not want the article with a null value exception.

Answer (score 1):

You should work according to your logic implemented in your class, if you define a constructor with REQUIRED parameters, then you should expect system raises warnings. If you don't want those warnings then you should create an empty constructor: `Item();` and initialize your variables with default values or set `?` per every data type.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends a lot of your needs but,instead of making nullable the complete Item you could not mark all attributes as `required`, Instead you could:

```
class Item {
class Item {
  Item(
      {this.depth = 0, required this.author, this.dead = false, this.pubTime}) {
    this.pubTime ??= DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch;
  }

  int depth;
  String author;
  bool dead;
  int? pubTime;
}
}
```

Depending of your business logic and requirements it could make sense to you to always declare an item dead attribute false by default, setting the date to the current time , and always require the author name it all depends.
For testing purposes you could make a small factory constructor of your item that only takes a few parameters such as:

```
  factory Item.test() => Item(
        author: "Peter",
        dead: true,
        depth: 42,
    ...// All other attributes
      );
```

I recommend you to read a little more about dart constructors like in this [article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/deconstructing-dart-constructors-e3b553f583ef)